# Extending the Stack Library

Tags: java, inheritance, stack

The EStack class works fine and gives the resulted output (which is taking the top element and putting a copy of it in whatever spot of the stack is specified in the method pushdown).

However, I could only get it to work for Integers (hence turning most things to Integer). How could I get this to work for any type of object put in the stack (int, string, char, double, float, etc.)?

```
import java.util.*;

public class EStack extends Stack{

    public static void pushdown(Stack s, int i){
        Integer marker = (Integer) s.size() - i;
        Integer top = (Integer) s.peek();
        Stack temp = new Stack();
        while(s.empty() != true){
            Integer elem = (Integer) s.pop();
            temp.push(elem);
        }
        while(temp.empty() != true){
            if(marker == s.size()){
                s.push(top);
            }
            Integer elem = (Integer) temp.pop();
            s.push(elem);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Stack s = new Stack();
        s.push(1);
        s.push(2);
        s.push(3);
        s.push(4);

        pushdown(s, 2);
        while(s.empty() != true){
            System.out.println(s.pop());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
4
3
4
2
1
```

Comment: Through the magic of generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work since Stack takes in `Object`:

```
public static void pushdown(Stack s, int i){
    Integer marker = (Integer) s.size() - i;
    Object top = s.peek();
    Stack temp = new Stack();
    while(s.empty() != true){
        Object elem = s.pop();
        temp.push(elem);
    }
    while(temp.empty() != true){
        if(marker == s.size()){
            s.push(top);
        }
        Object elem = temp.pop();
        s.push(elem);
    }
}
```

Basically I removed all the Integer casts.

Comment: Missed the first one `Integer marker = (Integer) s.size() - i;` But this does work. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome @Richie, the `marker` is still just a integer from my understanding?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how java.util.Stack (that you are extending) does it with generics. Here's the 
[Oracle generics documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/generics.html).

If you look at java.util.Stack, you'll notice that it's actually called `Stack<E>`, which can be read as "A stack of objects of type E" and throughout the class, where there would normally be the type of the objects in the stack (Integer in your case), there is instead "E".